# Unable to remove date from altacv cvenet

Tags: altacv

Basically, I wanted to add a projects section in my altacv latex resume, one that had only a title and then ordered events, something like below-

[image: problem I'm facing]

The code for this has 4 arguments-

```
\cvevent{Test}{}{}{}

\begin{itemize}

    \item make this date symbol go away please 

\end{itemize}
```

Is there no way to get rid of the date symbol? I just want it to be totally ignored, so that I can shift up my text and have a title + ordered list combination.

Alternatively, is there some other way I can achieve what I am looking for?

Thank you, been stuck at this for hours.

---

Code structure looks like this:

```
\documentclass[10pt,a4paper]{altacv}

\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[default]{lato}
\usepackage{graphicx}
```

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Please make your code compilable (if possible), or at least complete it with `\documentclass{...}`, the required `\usepackage`'s, `\begin{document}`, and `\end{document}`. That may seem tedious to you, but think of the extra work it represents for TeX.SX users willing to give you a hand. Help them help you: remove that one hurdle between you and a solution to your problem.

Comment: @TobiBS Have updated my code, thank you

Comment: Sounds like https://github.com/liantze/AltaCV. Why not just use `\cvsubsection{Test}` instead of `\cvevent`?